# How to create multiple instances of a service in Android?

Tags: android, service

I have created a service `DownloadService1` which is using object  `downloadData1`.
Now I want to perform 2 download operations `simultaneously` by using objects `downloadData1` and `downloadData2`, but I dont want to create an `extact` copy of `DownloadService1`, say  `DownloadService2` that will work with `downloadData2`.
Is there any way to create multiple instances of Service to achieve what i want ?

Comment: Why not have *one* `DownloadService` that downloads two things simultaneously?

Comment: @CommonWare no, two DownloadService with the same code,only difference is that one is using downloadData1 and other downloadData2

Answer (score 2):

> How to create multiple instances of a service in Android?

**AFAIK** it is not possible to create multiple instances of a service

Only one instances of service will run

if you call `startService()` multiple times does not result in starting multiple service.

when you call `startService()` there are two only possibility

> If Service in not started previously then it will start as per service life cycle
>
> If Service is previously started then only `onStartCammand()` will get called with desired intent which you have passed to it .

for more information read docs [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: So do i need to write "DownloadService2" again?

Answer (score 0):

How about you create an Object that can handle multiple download simultaneously, and then you can use this Object in your service. You can checkout my workaround for the download:

```
public class MediaDownloadClient extends MediaDownloadListener implements Runnable {
private static final int DOWNLOAD_TRACKER_BREAK = 500; //ms

private static MediaDownloadClient singleton;

private final Object lock = new Object();
private OkHttpClient mHttpClient;
private Thread downloadThread;//main download thread
private ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private boolean downloading = false, running = false;

private Queue<MediaDownloadEntry> downloadQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();

private int stopDownloadId = 0;

private MediaDownloadClient() {
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.connectTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    builder.readTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    mHttpClient = builder.build();
}

public static MediaDownloadClient getInstance() {
    if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new MediaDownloadClient();
        singleton.start();
    }
    return singleton;
}


public static boolean download(String url, String toPath) throws IOException {
    if (url == null || toPath == null) return false;

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder().url(url);
    Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(builder.build()).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) return false;


    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(response.body().byteStream());
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(toPath));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 200];
        int read;
        while ((read = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        if (bos != null) bos.close();
        if (bis != null) bis.close();

    }
    return true;
}

public void addListener(Listener listener) {
    super.addListener(listener);
}

public void removeListener(Listener listener) {
    super.removeListener(listener);
}

public void queue(MediaModel item, String toPath) {
    MediaDownloadEntry download = new MediaDownloadEntry();
    download.setMedia(item);

    //serving as downloadId.. to keep track of the download
    download.downloadId = 2 + new Random().nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    download.downloadTo = toPath;
    download.downloadState = MediaDownloadEntry.STATE_QUEUED;
    downloadQueue.add(download);

    dispatchDownloadEvent(download, MediaDownloadEntry.STATE_QUEUED);
    synchronized (lock) {
        lock.notify();
    }
}

public void queue(String url, String fileName, String toPath, int mediaType) {
    MediaDownloadEntry model = new MediaDownloadEntry();
    model.dataUrl = url;
    model.mediaType = mediaType;
    model.fileName = fileName;

    queue(model, toPath);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (downloading || downloadQueue.size() == 0) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
            }

            try {
                MediaDownloadEntry queue = downloadQueue.poll();
                if (queue != null) {
                    downloading = true;
                    download(queue);
                }
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
            downloading = false;
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
}

private void start() {
    if (downloadThread == null)
        downloadThread = new Thread(this);

    downloadThread.start();
    running = true;
}

private void download(MediaDownloadEntry queue) {
    DownloadTracker tracker = new DownloadTracker(queue);
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    try {
        Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder().url(queue.dataUrl);
        Response response = mHttpClient.newCall(builder.build()).execute();
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(response.body().byteStream());
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(queue.downloadTo));

        if (queue.fileSize == 0) {
            String len = response.header("Content-Length", "0");
            queue.fileSize = Integer.parseInt(len);
        }
        if (queue.fileName == null) {
            queue.fileName = response.header("Content-Name", "file");
        }
        if (queue.mimeType == null) {
            queue.mimeType = response.header("Content-Type", "media");
        }

        queue.downloadState = MediaDownloadEntry.STATE_START;
        dispatchDownloadEvent(queue, MediaDownloadEntry.STATE_START);

        downloadTracker(tracker);//start download tracking
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1000];//1MB buffer allocated
        while ((tracker.read = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            if (stopDownloadId == queue.downloadId) {
                queue.downloadState = MediaDownloadEntry.ERROR;
                dispatchDownloadEvent(queue, MediaDownloadEntry.ERROR);
                break;
            }

            tracker.count += tracker.read;
            bos.write(buffer, 0, tracker.read);
        }

        queue.downloadState = MediaDownloadEntry.STATE_COMPLETED;
        dispatchDownloadEvent(queue, MediaDownloadEntry.STATE_COMPLETED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tracker.read = -1;//to terminate tracker
        queue.downloadState = MediaDownloadEntry.ERROR;
        dispatchDownloadEvent(queue, MediaDownloadEntry.ERROR);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bis != null) bis.close();
            if (bos != null) bos.close();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
}

public void stopDownload(int downloadId) {
    stopDownloadId = downloadId;
}

private void downloadTracker(final DownloadTracker tracker) {
    threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(DOWNLOAD_TRACKER_BREAK); //pause to allow first updateLike
                while (tracker.read != -1) {
                    tracker.download.downloadCount = tracker.count;
                    tracker.download.downloadState = MediaDownloadEntry.STATE_PROGRESS;
                    dispatchDownloadEvent(tracker.download, MediaDownloadEntry.STATE_PROGRESS);

                    Thread.sleep(DOWNLOAD_TRACKER_BREAK); //break for another 300ms
                }
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }//end run
    });
}

public void terminate() {
    running = false;
    downloadQueue = null;
}

private class DownloadTracker {
    int read, count;
    MediaDownloadEntry download;

    DownloadTracker(MediaDownloadEntry model) {
        this.download = model;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class MediaDownloadEntry extends MediaModel {
public static final int ERROR = -1;
public static final int STATE_QUEUED = 0;
public static final int STATE_PROGRESS = 1;
public static final int STATE_START = 1;
public static final int STATE_COMPLETED = 2;

public int downloadCount, downloadState;
public int downloadId;
public String downloadUrl, downloadTo;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return ((MediaDownloadEntry) o).downloadId == downloadId;
}
```

}